# {"Keyword not supported.\r\nParameter name: port3306;username"} c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to connect a combobox to a tabel in my local database
but on line:

```
MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
```

I get this error

> {"Keyword not supported.\r\nParameter name: port3306;username"}

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Fillcombo();
    }

    void Fillcombo() {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port3306;username=username;password=password";
        string Query = "select * from hotel";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString("Rom_nr");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
            }

        }
        finally
        {
        }
```

Comment: The error tells you the exact problem - your connection string is wrong. `port3306` isn't a valid parameter.

Comment: Try changing `datasource=localhost;port3306` to `datasource=localhost:3306`

Comment: @BeanFrog Is `datasource=localhost:3306` correct syntax? Shouldn't it be `datasource=localhost;port=:3306`?

Comment: @Devart yes, but without the `:`! `datasource=localhost;port=3306` see https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-2/

Comment: I meant, shouldn't it be `datasource=localhost;port=3306`?

Comment: this did work its all fine now